# Using SQS and token vending machine on non ios and andorid devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, tvm

I am developing an app on both j2me and windows phone 8 platform and the app will need to access the Amazon SQS.

Of course this has to be done securely. I can only see the android and ios sdk, how do I securely (with the token vending machine) access the Amazon SQS on other platform other than ios and android?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no TVM sample for C#, you may be interested in this blog post - http://notebookheavy.com/2012/04/19/amazon-simpledb-for-windows-phone-part-4-tvmclient/

The author has converted much of the Android implementation into C# and it may give you a head start.

You may also be interested in using web identity federation. [This](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx2KW5KYMRE681I/Web-Identity-span-class-matches-Federation-span-using-the-AWS-SDK-for-NET) blog post explains how to use that with the AWS SDK for .NET.